# How can I extend jQuery in Coffeescript so I append the Coffeescript class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, extend

What I want to do is append a `Circle` in main like this: `stage.append circle`. I thought that Circle extends jQuery would be good solution, but that doesn't seem to work.

My current code:

Circle.coffee:

```
define [], () ->
  class Circle
    constructor: (@x, @y, @radius) ->
      @circle = $ document.createElement "div"
      @circle.addClass "circle"
      @circle.width @radius * 2
      @circle.height @radius * 2
      @circle.css
        left: @x
        top: @y
```

Main.coffee:

```
define [
  'object/Circle'
], (Circle) ->

  stage = $ "#main"

  circle = new Circle 350, 350, 100
  stage.append circle.circle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this. You have to take *two* cases into account. The first case is where the selector is a string pointing to an existing object in the DOM. The second case is where the selector is pointing to a 'new' element or when the selector is pointing to another object.

For the first case you need to copy a newly created jQuery object into the instance. This in order to give jQuery a chance to search the DOM. The easiest way to check for this is to check if selector is a string and not an HTML tag. This method is probably not thorough enough, but for basic usage it works.

For the second case you can *call* init with the **this** as the first parameter. This will create a new jQuery object around the current instance.

```
class Element extends jQuery
  constructor: (selector, context) ->
    # When selector is a string and not an html tag:
    # body, #my-id, .error-class etc.
    if typeof selector is 'string' and not selector.match /^<.*>$/
      jQuery.extend true, this, jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, jQuery document)

    # When selector is a jQuery object
    else if selector instanceof jQuery
      jQuery.extend true, this, selector

    else
      # When selector points to an object which doesn't exist in the DOM:
      # <div>, document.createElement('span')
      # Or when selector is an object
      jQuery.fn.init.call this, selector, context

    @constructor = jQuery
```

Now you can extend *Element* to create all kinds of custom elements.

```
class Square extends Element
  constructor: (size) ->
    super(document.createElement('div')) # Square is a div with no parent
    @width size
    @height size
    @css 'background', 'repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, blue, blue 15px, green 15px, green 30px)'
```

And use *Element* like *$*

```
new Element('body').append(new Square())
```